# jquery event triggered when scrolled past element

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, element

I am building a horizontal scrolling website to display images.  The slideshow would contain different 'series' of photos.  I want to add an ID to the first image of each series.

When you scroll horizontally past the first image with the ID, a div box containing the series' title would show.  When you scroll past a new image with a different ID, it's series' title would show.

How can I use jQuery to make this happen?

This is what my HTML would look like.

```
<div style="overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
<img src="p001.jpg" id="people">
<img src="p002.jpg">
<img src="p003.jpg">
<img src="p004.jpg">
<img src="p005.jpg">

<img src="l001.jpg" id="landscape">
<img src="l002.jpg">
<img src="l003.jpg">
<img src="l004.jpg">
<img src="l005.jpg">

<img src="bw001.jpg" id="blackwhite">
<img src="bw002.jpg">
<img src="bw003.jpg">
<img src="bw004.jpg">
<img src="bw005.jpg">

</div>

<div>
The title of the series would show here
</div>
```

Does this make sense?  I hope...

Comment: Could you supply markup for how you want to add several titles to different series? Now it’s just one div with no relations to any ID.

Comment: Waypoints is a jQuery plugin for doing this vertically, but I've never tried it horizontally and pretty sure it doesn't do that http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 0):

Tryout GalleryView:

http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/

You may find this easier to display the title for each image instead of trapping the id and changing it on the fly.

Comment: I'm not looking for an image slideshow, I am using an image slider.  But thanks anyways.